# EXPLAIN what this VB CODE means

Tags: vb.net, data-conversion

```
Function convertToText(ByVal data As String) As String
Dim result As String = Nothing
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In data.ToCharArray
        j *= 2
        If c = "1"c Then j += 1
        i += 1
        If i = 8 Then
            i = 0
            result &= Chr(j)
            j = 0
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

It converts binary to text but its a bit difficult for me to understand the logic behind it. 
Someone please help.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything, since it doesn't compile! (A `End If` is missing, `data` is not declared) Also, it is difficult to read, as it is not indented correctly. Please include code that does compile!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes posting using the app is difficult, but its now edited. And it does compile

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to convert a text containing a binary number representing 8 bit character codes to a string containing these characters.

The for each loop loops over all binary digits ("0" or "1") of the input. The code of each result character is computed and after every 8 input characters the code is considered to be complete and the new character whose code was determined is added to the result (`result &= Chr(j)` is the same as `result = result & Chr(j)`. `Chr(j)` converts an Integer containing a character code into a character). The variable `i` counts the bits.

The variable `j` holds the character code. If a bit is "1", then 1 is added to `j` (`j += 1` is the same as `j = j + 1`), but not if it is "0".

A "1" in the right most bit position has a (decimal) value of 1. The next to its left a value of 2. The next 4 and so on. The value doubles for each position until it reaches 128 for the left most bit of an 8 bit number. Therefore `j` is doubled on each loop (`j *= 2` is the same as `j = j * 2`).

Example with just 4 bits:

```
data = "1010"
```

The binary number 1010 means

```
1 * 8 + 0 * 4 + 1 * 2 + 0 * 1 = (decimal)10
```

The code does this

```
j = 0      => 0

j *= 2     => 0
j += 1     => 1  'since c = "1"

j *= 2     => 2
'no  += 1         since c = "0"

j *= 2     => 4
j += 1     => 5  'since c = "1"

j *= 2     => 10
'no  += 1         since c = "0"
```

The first `1` we added is doubled 3 times and becomes `8`. The second `1` we added is doubled only once and becomes `2`. 8 + 2 = 10.